# Change Image on div onclick()

Tags: javascript, html

I want to load different image on different div clicks. How do I know which div is clicked? Do I have to pass the div class as argument?

```js
    <script type="javascript">
    function ChangeLibaas() {

        
    }
    </script>
```

```html
    <div class="Indeximages">
        <img src="images/white.png" id="libaasImage" class="img-responsive jubbahImage" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12  nopadding customTabs">
        <h2>Pick a Colour</h2>
        <div class="col-md-3 colourBlue" onclick="ChangeLibaas()"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 colourBlack" onclick="ChangeLibaas()"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 colourGreen" onclick="ChangeLibaas()"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest inline: pass (this):

```
<div class="col-md-3 colourBlue" onclick="ChangeLibaas(this)"></div>
```

and use it :

```
function ChangeLibaas(theClickedDiv) { 
   var img = "images/"+
     theClickedDiv.className.split("colour")[1].toLowerCase()+".png"; // take the colour
   document.getElementById("libaasImage").src=img;
}
```

To make it all neater, use an attribute and unobtrusive code

```
window.onload=function() {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div.col-md-3");
  for (var i=0;i<divs.length;i++) {
    divs[i].onclick=function() {
      document.getElementById("libaasImage").src="images/"+
        this.getAttribute("data-color")+".png";
    }
  }
}
```

using

```
<div class="col-md-3 colourBlue" data-color="blue""></div>
```

Comment: I'd write a function to get the colour name from the classes and I think it's png pictures :P

Comment: Or, even simpler - use data attributes for image URL. ;)

Comment: Yep, plus one, just update HTML accordingly, so OP can understand, and...i would even put extension to data (just in case!). :) So, simplest usage: image.src=this.getAttribute('data-src')...

Comment: That is doable. Then we need to change to images\blue.jpg and if that folder change we have to change each attr

Comment: Thanks for your help guys but I am getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByID is not a function

Comment: Typo. getElementById - fixed - I also put images/ in front of the png now

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working. What does window.onload=function() do?

Comment: It executes the code inside it after the Dom/page has loaded

Answer (score 1):

You can pass as an argument, like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12  nopadding customTabs">
    <h2>Pick a Colour</h2>
    <div class="col-md-3 colourBlue" onclick="ChangeLibaas(this)"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 colourBlack" onclick="ChangeLibaas(this)"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 colourGreen" onclick="ChangeLibaas(this)"></div>
</div>
```

And then:

```
<script type="javascript">
function ChangeLibaas(sender) {
    var div = sender;
}
</script>
```

But it's better if you use event listeners.

Comment: and how do I change the image?

Comment: This is not what you asked in the question, but you'll need a little bit more of code for that.

Comment: you get your image element with `getElementById('libaasImage')` then change its `src` attribute with `setAttribute('src', 'whatever_you_want')`

Answer (score 0):

I hope it can be useful:

In your html

```
<div class="Indeximages">
    <img src="images/white.png" id="libaasImage" class="img-responsive jubbahImage" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="col-md-12  nopadding customTabs">
    <h2>Pick a Colour</h2>
    <button class="col-md-3" data-color="colourBlue" onclick="ChangeLibaas(this)">Blue</div>
    <button class="col-md-3" data-color="colourBlack" onclick="ChangeLibaas(this)">Black</div>
    <button class="col-md-3" data-color="colorGreen" onclick="ChangeLibaas(this)">Green</div>
</div>
```

In javascript, code looks like:

```
function ChangeLibaas(origin) {
    var color = origin.dataset.color;
    var img = document.getElementById('libaasImage');
    img.src = color + ".jpg";
}
```